# Working with screen and emacs

Tags: gnu-screen, keyboard-shortcuts, emacs

I'm working with emacs (on the terminal) and I use screen to switch between terminals. The key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is grabbed by screen. Is there a way to change screen key binding?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure, you can change the binding in either Screen or Emacs.

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> in Screen, which is used by very few applications. It's used in the terminal to send the [QUIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGQUIT) signal — a stronger version of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, which fewer applications catch and may produce a core dump. That's rarely useful, and if you need it you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> <kbd>\</kbd>. A bigger argument against <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> is that it's hard to type on some keyboard layouts. Anyway, pick the key you prefer.

To change the Screen escape key, use the `escape` directive in `~/.screenrc`:

```
escape ^\\\
```

In Emacs, `C-a` normally moves to the beginning of the line; you can use <kbd>Home</kbd> instead. `C-x C-a` is not bound. That leaves modes with custom bindings for `C-a` or `C-x C-a` or `C-c C-a`. If you choose `C-\`, it's normally bound to `toggle-input-method`, which is useful if you write in multiple languages and useless otherwise. You can rebind it to a different key with `global-set-key` in your `~/.emacs`:

```
;; overrides a binding for `suspend-frame', which is also bound on `C-x C-z'
(global-set-key "\C-z" toggle-input-method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create `~/.screenrc` containing:

```
escape ^Zz
```

Then use Ctrl-Z instead of Ctrl-A to control screen.